# Exclude C# Compiler Warnings From Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Is there anyway to exclude Compiler warnings from the **problems** tab for C# Omnisharp in Visual Studio Code? I only want to see red compiler errors problems:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, there is a filter box, and I just entered *error* and it filtered them down!

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750569/vscode-remove-warnings-from-problems-tab