# How can I filter out problems in excluded files from the Problems Panel in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working in a very old Java project (created originally on eclipse) using VS Code and the official plugin for Java.
The project has some folders which are not longer used/valid and I hide them because they don't compile neither. I was able to do this using "files.exclude" in settings.json file.

The thing is I don't want to see those problem in my "Problem" panel. In addition every time I launch my debugger I get a message saying "Build failed, do you want to continue?" which is really annoying.

So, is it possible to hide those problem which belong to my ignored folders?

Comment: Don't have an answer, but you can always delete/move those folders somewhere else.

Answer (score 26):

This might be helpful to you.  v1.41 is adding the ability to filter the Problems pane to not show errors/warnings/info/current file only/hide excluded files.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#problems-panel

[image: filter problems pane]

Comment: the feature for hiding excluded files (which is more relevant to what is being asked here than showing the active file only) was released in 1.23.

Answer (score 16):

Your use-case is exactly the one described in [Microsoft/vscode issue 43135](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43135), covered by [issue 22289](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22289)

This has been covered by the `files.exclude` setting that you are using, and the issue 22289 animation shows it does apply to problems too:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10746682/38645715-59280224-3de5-11e8-9436-5cfccf737ebb.gif]

> Count badge shows total number of problems.
>   Filtered count is shown in the badge in filter input box.
>
> Filters in Problems view are view only filters. It will only exclude in Problems view.

So... that does not translate to the File Explorer view.

Hence the request:

> I like to have a `files.problemExclude` in settings
>
> Likes other comment in this issue, `files.exclude` will exclude the entire `node_module` folder from project explorer, which is not desired.
>   I just do not want to see any problem in my `node_module` folder.

That was requested, but closed in [vscode issue 52011](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52011).

As commented, deleting those folders (kept in version control in a past revision/commit) is the simplest solution for now.

Answer (score 2):

The April 2018 (1.23) release of VS Code added a filter input to the Problems Panel, where you can type glob patterns to include or exclude. Multiple patterns can be specified, separated by commas, and prefixing a pattern with a `!` character means that the pattern will be used for excluding rather than including. See related description/docs for the feature [in the relase notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_problems-view-filtering).

There's also an option in the dropdown filter menu beside the text input to toggle whether the `files.exclude` setting is honoured for filtering. You should see a "Toggle Excluded Files" option in the filter dropdown menu, and after it is enabled, it will instead read "Hide Excluded Files". The filter dropdown menu was originally just a gear icon in version 1.23 to toggle that behaviour, but it was later [expanded in 1.41](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_problems-panel) to include other options, such as filtering by problem type, and showing only problems in the active file.

---

Relevant historical discussion is in [Ignore folders/files in Problems view
#22289](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22289). See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22289#issuecomment-380611244), where Sandeep Somavarapu (one of the VS Code maintainers) updated that VS Code added the feature to toggle honouring `files.exclude`.

It was [later suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22289#issuecomment-389275576) in that same issue ticket (and also in [a separate one, #43135](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43135)) for there to be a `files.problemExclude`/`problems.exclude` setting, to which Sandeep replied:

> I think the right and efficient approach is to extensions provide options to exclude.[...] please check with the extension to provide the exclude option.
>
> Since this issue is resolved, I am locking it. Please open new issues for new requirements/bugs.