# How can I disable problems for virtual files in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a .Net Core application and I keep running into this problem where I get all sorts of random issues appearing in the Problems window in VSCode for "__virtual" files. There are no problems in the actual razor page (.cshtml) and everything is working how we would expect. Is there a way in VSCode to mass ignore all problems from __virtual files?

[image: Problems in __virtual file]

Comment: You need to exclude those files (with extension "**/.razor__virtual.html"
To exclude them go to "File/Preferences/Settings" and then search for Files:Exclude, you can also mark association to these extensions as "text" files, so the compiler/linter will not touch them.

Comment: related: [How can I filter out problems in excluded files from the Problems Panel in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53750569/11107541)

Answer (score 6):

This started to happen to me after the latest update of Visual Studio Code.

My solution was to configure file association for `.razor__virtual.html` files into `text`

1. Open visual studio code
2. Click `Settings` icon in the left bottom and click `Settings`
3. In the search box, search for `Files: Associations` (Copy-paste this)
4. Click [**Add Item**] button and enter `**/*.razor__virtual.html` for key, `text` for value.

It should look like this,
[image: Files Associations VS Code]

Done!