# Is it possible to exclude folders from the problems tab in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with a file that causes the problems tab to EXPLODE with warnings, and the reason is that I only use that file inside of another "main" file, which means that instead of creating a variable in every single one of the files that I use, I only create it in the "main" one, but VScode has no idea about that, so it trashes my problems tab with errors of missing variables.

So I just thought if it was possible to exclude the folder with problematic files from the problems tab or if there is any other way to avoid the warning diarrhea.

And although I did see somewhere unrelated to this that it is possible to use `.json` files or something to control VScode, I know nothing about it

Comment: use the filter of the PROBLEMS tab, top right

Comment: I think this comment shows this feature: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22289#issuecomment-380611244. Perhaps you just need to add a `files.exclude` setting in the configs json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I filter out problems in excluded files from the Problems Panel in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750569/how-can-i-filter-out-problems-in-excluded-files-from-the-problems-panel-in-vs-co)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to try a language specific solution. As far as September 2023, and as far as I was able to research, there is NOT a VSCode solution for this.

In `Dart`, you may use in your workspace file:

```json
// flutter.code-workspace
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "cinemapedia/lib",
            "path": "cinemapedia/lib"
        },
        // OTHER PATHS
    ],
    "settings": {
        "problems.decorations.enabled": false,
        "dart.analysisExcludedFolders": [
            "C:/Users/carlo/repos/_practice/flutter/cinemapedia/lib/config", // It takes everything inside the folder.
            "C:/Users/carlo/repos/_practice/flutter/cinemapedia/lib/main.dart", // As far as I was able to find out, it does not work in files where the error is originated in subordinated files (in the case of imported classes, for example).
            "" // It takes everything at the workspace level.
        ]
    },
}
```

Other language, may have options similar to `"dart.analysisExcludedFolders"` ([Dart docs](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartanalysisexcludedfolders)). Here's a gif displaying the proposed workaround:

[image]

Hopefully, other languages allow to target files with higher accuracy.

- Working with workspaces in VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces

Answer (score 7):

There appears to not be any direct way to achieve exclusion of a folder from the problem diagnostics.

The exclusion of folders seems to have been delegated to extensions according to this issue thread
[vscode issue #22289](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22289)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the anwser above I implement this for a simple folder, when you don't create a workspace! So just add these lines in a .vscode/settings.json file in the root of the folder you opened.

```js
// projectwithsomedartnotstructured/.vscode/settings
{
    "problems.decorations.enabled": false,
    "dart.analysisExcludedFolders": [
        ""
    ]
}
```

[How to add for a simple folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLrHi.png)

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for Python (Pylance), the `python.analysis.ignore` setting allows you to exclude files and directories from analysis, even if they are otherwise included in the analysis by other settings. From the setting's description:

> Paths of directories or files whose diagnostic output (errors and
> warnings) should be suppressed even if they are an included file or
> within the transitive closure of an included file.

Hope that helps.