# Microsoft Edge Tools warnings in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, edge-devtools

Which tool/parser/linter are the following errors/warnings coming from?

[image]

These errors are about an HTML file that resides inside the project folder, but I want VSCode to ignore it. I have searched for **Microsoft Edge Tools** related settings in VSCode but haven't found any that could do this.

Is there a way to ignore this file (or better the entire sub-folder)? These HTML files come from legacy sources and I don't have control over their syntactic health, so I want VSCode not to report these problems.

Comment: related, but not a dup-target (for the reason in the top answer there): https://stackoverflow.com/q/67508947/11107541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. These messages appears to be coming from **WebHint**. It looks like VSCode has this as a built-in *feature* (i.e. you don't need to explicitly install it from Extensions pane).

The feature can be turned off using VSCode Settings. Name of the setting is `vscode-edge-devtools.webhint` and is turned on by default. Turn it off and all these messages will vanish away.